# Access old get parameters in URL after a post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form in RoR with a controller action that looks up a record via the get parameter.

```
def respond 
  if request.post? 
    # Submit logic here...

    # cannot lookup this way to fill the form out again 
    # @current_message = Saved_message.find_by_id(params[:msg_id])
  elsif request.get? 
    @current_message = Saved_message.find_by_id(params[:msg_id])
  end
end
```

I can't use the `params[:msg_id]` to lookup the message again because it's a post request and I don't resend the get parameters. However, the get parameters remain in the url such as `.../messages/respond?msg_id=2`. I can get around this by passing in a hidden field with a different parameter name like `<%= form.hidden_field :msg_id_2, value: params[:msg_id] %>`. Then I can lookup the `@current_message` via the `params[:msg_id_2]`. However, I don't like this solution. Any advice to access the now inaccessible get parameter?

Comment: Why are you using the same action do handle `get` and `post` ?. Why do you need to name it `msg_id_2` ?, why not the same parameter name ?. The options here are either what you said(pass the parameter again in the post request) or you could store it in a session, and then get it from there in the post request.

Comment: @fanta You are correct, I can use the same name but I must pass it as a hidden form parameter still. I am using the same action because it's a custom action. How do I specify which controller action I want to call with a form submit button? I didn't think that was possible. Here is the current submit button `<%= form.submit "Send", :class=>'btn ',  data: { confirm: 'Confirm sending message.' }%>`

Comment: A form submit button is usually bound to a form, the form is the one that has the URL.

Comment: Is the form submitted asynchronously or via standard http? You should really be using separate routes/actions for displaying (`GET`) and submitting (`POST`) the form. Then, in your controller action that handles the form submission, you can simply render the `GET` action instead of a redirect should the form parameters have any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use RESTful routes so that you do not have to care about such issues.

since you are not posting much about the actual code or problem you are trying to solve, i can just assume what might be the issue here and how to solve it.

Comment: I agree that RESTful routes are important. But how do you do custom actions when the other routes are already used? Are you saying that every possible action should correspond to one of the 7 routes? What about two different update operations? Should that be accomplished by passing different parameters in the body and determining which action to take that way?

Comment: in an ideal world all actions should map to a restful route. since that is usually not desirable, you can add more restful routes as member or collection routes https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions